# Amazon Serverless Application Model (SAM) conditional includes in a template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

Has anybody found any tricks to conditionally including something in a SAM template?  Here is the use case;

We have a sandbox where everything is in public subnets so our lambda functions don't need VPC access.  Also, there are no NAT gateways in this environment so if we do grant VPC access to the lambda they lose internet connection.  In our other environments however, the lambdas need VPC access as many resources are in private subnets.

So, in the above example, what would be the best way to only include the VPC configuration when an environment variable signifies we are not deploying to sandbox?

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Thanks all.

Comment: For simple scenarios you can use intrinsic conditional functions in templates but if it gets remotely complex then personally I would consider creating multiple templates, one per environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the `Fn::If` function combined with the `AWS::NoValue` value (for the case when you don’t want it).

Answer (score 1):

As Jason says above, the Fn::If does the job:

```
VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          !If
            - IsNotSandbox
            -
              - !Ref SecurityGroup
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
        SubnetIds:
          !If
            - IsNotSandbox
            -
              - !Ref SubNet1
              - !Ref SubNet2
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```